# Why cant i show error message?

Tags: php, html, validation

When username == username from the database and date == date from the database, it should echo an error message but instead it shows success. I tried using "=", but the result keeps echoing the error message even when the data is suppose to be correct. Please help.

These are my codes:

```
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])){

        $username=$_POST['username'];
        }
        else
        {
        $username=null;
        $usererr = "";
        }

     if(!empty($_POST['datepicker'])){
       $date = date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
       }
        else
        {
        $date=null;
        $dateerr = "";
        }

        $mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username, date FROM booking WHERE username='$username' and date ='$date'");

            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $date); 

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($cusername, $cdate);
            $stmt->fetch();

        if($cusername == $username && $cdate == $date){
            echo"You have already book this day. Please select another day";
        }
        else{
            echo"Success";
            $chdate = $date;
        }
         if($username && $date && $chdate){

        session_start();

        $mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");

        stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO booking (, , , , )
                            VALUES ('',''");

        $result = $stmt->execute();

        }
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: You should use placeholders in the query instead of the variable name. `WHERE username=?` You're actually trying to quote the variable there rather.

Comment: have you tried echo date and cdate? are they completely equal?

Comment: Tip: instead of using 'else' to "reset" variables. Start with defining them with "empty" values. Cleaner code and no need in the else statements no more.

Comment: Personally, i'd put a condition within a condition

Comment: There's nothing messier than a nested condition :)

Comment: @Mr.K.O.Rolling yes they are equal. however, if i put "=" for only when the date is empty then it will run success else even if the dates ($date and $cdate) are different, it will still prompt an error message

Comment: var_dump each of the 4 variables to make sure they have the exact content and length before you go through the if loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
$date = date('y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
```

this will return year as "17" for 2017, try like this

```
 $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datepicker']));
```

Comment: @prozcay do a small test. echo all the varieables "$cusername,  $username,  $cdate,  $date" just before if condition, you will have idea what these variable carry data before comparision

Comment: during echo does $cdate and $data are same ? and $cname and $name text are same ?

Comment: @prozcay "SELECT username, date FROM booking WHERE username='$username' AND date ='$date'

Comment: i have reedit my codes, it works but why when i select the date eg. 2017-02-02, it cant insert into the database?